# CRC16 ISO 13239 Implementation

Tags: c#, crc, crc16

i'm trying to implement Crc16 in C#. I already tried many different implementations, but most of them gives me different values. Here are some of the codes that i already used.

```
    private static int POLYNOMIAL = 0x8408;
    private static int PRESET_VALUE = 0xFFFF;

    public static int crc16(byte[] data)
    {
        int current_crc_value = PRESET_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            current_crc_value ^= data[i] & 0xFF;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((current_crc_value & 1) != 0)
                {
                    current_crc_value = (current_crc_value >> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
                }
                else
                {
                    current_crc_value = current_crc_value >> 1;
                }
            }
        }
        current_crc_value = ~current_crc_value;

        return current_crc_value & 0xFFFF;
    }
```

this is the another implementation that i used but both gives different values

```
    const ushort polynomial = 0xA001;
    ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

    public ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }

    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }

    public Crc16()
    {
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else
                {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            table[i] = value;
        }
    }
```

The value I`m using is an ***Octet String***  **"[jp3]TEST [fl]Flashing[/fl]"** and its expected value is **95F9** in hex. This is an example on the guide of NTCIP protocol

Thanks

Comment: there are many possible input parameters for CRC-16. It isn't a single algorithm like MD5. For this reason, for example, your two fragments have two different `polynomial`/`POLYNOMIAL` (and other different things)

Comment: For example in this page http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html various crc-16 used by various standards are showed.

Comment: I've found the document you are speaking of: http://www.ite.org/standards/1203v03-04%20Part%201%20dms2011.pdf Sadly there isn't a single real example of how the CRC calculation.

Comment: Perhaps I've found the algorithm. It computes the only full example present.

Comment: The only example on this document is where it is defined like i said before, The algorithm is based on the CRC-16 algorithm defined in ISO 13239:2002 here on page 118 ntcip.org/library/documents/pdf/1203v0239b_rs.pdf. Also on this page there is an example of a text and its value on hex using CRC16."95 F9 2-byte checksum value for a MULTI-string value of '[jp3]TEST [fl]Flashing[/fl]' in hex". It still is not clear where i should look for, or even how can i make it

Comment: This is a bog-standard HDLC CRC-16: ISO/IEC 13239:2002 is "High-level data link control (HDLC) procedures". You'll find an implementation in anything that speaks PPP, as that's just HDLC UI (unnumbered information). For the C code, see e.g. [RFC1662 p.19](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1662#page-19).

Comment: Other things that use it, if you wish to refer to other free-to-download standards, are ITU T-REC-X.25 and ITU-T-REC-Q.921.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
static readonly ushort[] fcstab = new ushort[] { 
    0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf, 
    0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7, 
    0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e, 
    0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876, 
    0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd, 
    0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5, 
    0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c, 
    0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974, 
    0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb, 
    0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3, 
    0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a, 
    0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72, 
    0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9, 
    0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1, 
    0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738, 
    0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70, 
    0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7, 
    0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff, 
    0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036, 
    0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e, 
    0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5, 
    0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd, 
    0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134, 
    0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c, 
    0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3, 
    0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb, 
    0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232, 
    0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a, 
    0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1, 
    0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9, 
    0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330, 
    0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78 
};

static ushort compute_fcs(byte[] data)
{
    return compute_fcs(data, 0, data.Length);
}

static ushort compute_fcs(byte[] data, int start, int length)
{
    ushort fcs = 0xFFFF;

    int end = start + length;

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        fcs = (ushort)(((ushort)(fcs >> 8)) ^ fcstab[(fcs ^ data[i]) & 0xFF]);
    }

    return (ushort)(~fcs);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] pattern = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x07, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x34, 0x07, 0x07, 0x1C, 0x59, 0x34, 0x6F, 0xE1, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x06, 0x06, 0x7B, 0x3C, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0x3C, 0xC0 };

    // http://www.ite.org/standards/1203v03-04%20Part%201%20dms2011.pdf
    // Page 158, CRC = 0x52ED
    ushort fcs = compute_fcs(pattern); // 0x52ED
}
```

will work for the only test given here http://www.ite.org/standards/1203v03-04%20Part%201%20dms2011.pdf (around page 158, `CRC = 0x52ED`).

For the string example of the PDF, as written some pages later:

> " Indicates the CRC-16 (polynomial defined in ISO/IEC 3309) value 
>   created using the values of the dmsMessageMultiString (MULTI-Message), the 
>   dmsMessageBeacon, and the dmsMessagePixelService objects in the order listed, 
>   not including the OER type or length fields. Note that the calculation **shall 
>   assume a value of zero (0) for the dmsMessageBeacon object and/or for the 
>   dmsMessagePixelService object** if they are not supported

(emphasis added)

so:

```
string str = "[jp3]TEST [fl]Flashing[/fl]";
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
Array.Resize(ref bytes, bytes.Length + 2);

// Note that these two rows are useless, because the Array.Resize will have already filled with 0
bytes[bytes.Length - 2] = 0; // dmsMessageBeacon
bytes[bytes.Length - 1] = 0; // dmsMessagePixelService 

ushort fcs2 = compute_fcs(bytes); // 0xF995
var bytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(fcs2); // 0x95 0xF9
```

This shows that the protocol is little endian (as my PC, that is an Intel). In fact the CRC-16 of the string is 0xF995, but these 16 bits in memory appear as 0x95 0xF9 (as in the example, that shows the single bytes).

Comment: The Document defines that The algorithm is based on the CRC-16 algorithm defined in ISO 13239:2002 here on page 118 http://www.ntcip.org/library/documents/pdf/1203v0239b_rs.pdf

Comment: It worked here for this specif byte array, To me it is still unclear how to work with this string...

Comment: I Found one thing on this document around the page 175, Message CRC Parameter, Indicates the CRC-16 (polynomial defined in ISO/IEC 3309) value 
created using the values of the dmsMessageMultiString (MULTI-Message), the 
dmsMessageBeacon, and the dmsMessagePixelService objects in the order listed...

Comment: @FabioReis Found! You can see the added test. The algorithm was correct. The problem was on how to compose the string.

Answer (score 2):

There are many algorithms of CRC-16 calculation.

For instance:

- CRC-16-IBM which used in Modbus protocol, USB etc. is most popular.
- CRC-16-CCITT used in Bluetooth.

I use CRC-16-IBM in my applications which work with industrial controllers.

```
public static UInt16 FastCRC16(byte[] Buffer, UInt16 ui_length)
{

UInt16[] crc_table = {
0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040};

        UInt16 Crc = 65535;
        UInt16 x;
        for (UInt16 i = 0; i < ui_length; i++)
        {
            x = (UInt16)(Crc ^ Buffer[i]);
            Crc = (UInt16)((Crc >> 8) ^ crc_table[x & 0x00FF]);
        }

        return Crc;
}
```

Comment: The question was about a specific variant of CRC-16, with reference to a specific standard.